# Icons from my Home Directory in 23.10

Tags: desktop-environments, 23.10

I don't know how can I hide the icons of my Personal directory. This appeared two weeks ago, and I have tried various solutions unsuccessfully. If I delete a file I see on the desktop, it deletes directly in the Home directory.

[image: MyDesktop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop icons can be disabled through the Extension Manager (if you want to learn more about it, a link I found helpful was https://itsfoss.com/extension-manager/ ).

To install the program, run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

When you open it, you should see something like this:

[image: Extension Manager]

Go down to `System Extensions > Desktop Icons` and toggle the button to be disabled:

[image: Desktop Icons disabled]